# What are the differences between the 1993 and the 1994 Toyota 2.2L 5SFE?

Tags: toyota, camry, exhaust-manifold, swap

I need to get a new exhaust manifold for my 1996 Camry and I am only able to find manifolds that are specified to fit the '92-'93 vehicles. Is there any difference between the exhaust manifolds? If there is, are the connections any different, I.e. could I bolt up the '93 manifold to my '96 engine?

Overall this makes me curious about the differences between the 1992-1993 and 1994-1996 Toyota 4-cylinder 2.2L 5-SFE engines. If anyone has a good link I'd be grateful to see it, as I can't find any info.

Answer (score 1):

The same exhaust manifold gasket is used for 1992 and 1996 versions, the drawings (not guaranteed, however, to be the source of truth) are also identical.

The Toyota part number for the 1993 is 17141-74130, while the part number for the 1996 is 17141-74150.

So far it seems that the part will definitively bolt on to the engine if there are no extra protruding parts, other equipment in the engine bay, etc, that will prevent it from being positioned correctly. Also unclear is the connection to the exhaust pipe, it is possible it will require some modifications.

[image]